# What "boy" is Ronal referring to?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), Ronal is talking to mother Tulkun:

> Ronal: Your son is beautiful.
>
> Tulkun: Thank you. How is your baby?
>
> Ronal: My baby is strong. I met a **boy**.

What "boy" is Ronal referring to ?

Comment: You can see the full exchange here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZwKo5mkU4E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're confusing two conversations;**

[Ronal](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Ronal) is talking to the tulkun [Ro'a](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Ro%27a) about her unborn child.
[image]

[Tseriya](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Tsireya) then says (in a different conversation that we don't see the start of) that she "*met a boy*", the boy in question being Jake Sully's son, [Lo'ak](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lo%27ak).
[image]